# How to get rid of artefacts when converting `CVImageBufferRef` to OpenGL ES texture with `glTexImage2D`?

Tags: iphone, swift, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I tried to load texture from `CVImageBufferRef`:

```
func createTextureFromCVImageBufferRef(buffer: CVImageBufferRef) {
    let bufferHeight = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(buffer)
    let bufferWidth  = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(buffer)
    let bytesPerRow  = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(buffer)

    let w = bytesPerRow / 4 //  I option
    //let w = bufferWidth   //  II option
    let h = bufferHeight

    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(buffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: CVOptionFlags(0)))

    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER), GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER), GL_LINEAR)
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
    glTexParameteri(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T), GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)

    glTexImage2D(GLenum(GL_TEXTURE_2D), GLint(0), GLint(GL_RGBA), GLsizei(w), GLsizei(h), GLint(0), GLenum(GL_BGRA), GLenum(GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE), CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(buffer))
}
```

in 2 different ways:

1) `let w = bytesPerRow / 4`

2) `let w = bufferWidth`

Both options work perfectly on iPhone 5s, but I have artifacts on iPhone 6 because of `CVImageBufferRef` data alignment, as I understand. On iPhone 6 `bytesPerRow / 4` is equal to `752`, but `bufferWidth` equal to `750`. And in both cases I have the following artifacts:

In the first case:
there is a 2 pixel line in the right side of image. (It is part of the texture, not just black background view)

[image]

In the second case:
some hell is going on with the texture.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you have found you need to handle the row padding, but handle it in such a way that GL ignores it completely. Both your current approaches treat it like actual texture data, which is why it isn't working.

You can use `UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` to skip entire pixels, and `UNPACK_ALIGNMENT` to handle straggling byte padding (set via `glPixelStorei` before your texture upload).

I think in your case you want to set `UNPACK_ROW_LENGTH` to 752, and your `glTexImage2D` width parameter to 750.